# How to recreate this kind of line animation in Blender?

Tags: animation

I'd like to create a line animation like this one :

(Jupiter Ascending UI for info)

[image]

The question has been asked here and the person who created this animation replied, but with indications for Cinema 4d's Thinking Particles.

Can this be replicated in Blender ?

I tried with particles & forces but i cannot get near that. For example, one of the problems is that particles are going in all directions, intersecting paths of each others.

Comment: Try wind applied to curve shapes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Demo curve gif]

Try making an array of a plane along a curve. Deform the curve with a displace modifier driven by an object, then flatten the shape to a hidden plane.

[image: curve objects]

[image: Modifiers]

Make a material with a few brick textures, use a Mapping node to animate their offset. This can drive the bricks along the surface to make a fake particle effect.

[image: brick material]

Comment: Thanks for your insight, i was looking into brick textures into brick textures, following your comment, but your node setup works great, many thanks ! I'll have to study it as the control along the geometry is completely new to me...

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to use curves but they can be hard to make without using Animation Nodes or some other addon.
I have used particles with motion blur.

I made a curve and fit an object array along it. I applied a wind>curve force filed to the curve, while I applied a force>surface force field to the array object.

[image: curve and emitter]

[image: array surface]

[image: curve wind effect]

[image: surface force]

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is to make the lines not cross each other as seen in the reference image. I've come across a partial solution by emitting from a few aligned vertices with a curve guide, but it's still hard to control when i add more curves in it...

Comment: Ok then I'm thinking that procedural brick texture over an array curved plane might be better?