# How can I recreate this 2D " field of lines" in blender in a way that allows for dynamic or modifier animations

Tags: particles, lines

I am trying to recreate this artwork in blender in a way that allows me to use fields, dynamics, or modifiers to animate the lines as if they were grass being blown by the wind.

I have tried various iterations of hair particles with custom image objects, 3d object, the straight up hair system, the particle instance modifier to no avail. I am perhaps looking at this incorrectly. This technique might be more appropriate:

[How to recreate this kind of line animation in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88875/how-to-recreate-this-kind-of-line-animation-in-blender)

[image]

Any areas you think I might explore would be helpful. I am a relative noob at blender.

Comment: maybe have a look at the geometry node hair system or geon nodes in general